# Insert a new row into SQL Server 2012 from an e-mail

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email, webforms, sql-server-2012

I would like to insert/update data in SQL Server 2012 through an e-mail.
Scenario is simple: user sends us an email to a specific email address and we log it as an incident request.

I have searched the internet but I am unable to find a starting point. I would like to be pointed in the right direction. I have read that there used to be a feature to receive emails in SQL Server but it was deprecated in SQL Server 2012 and newer feature database mail doesn't support receiving emails.

Please guide me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of a service (written in whatever language you like) that can fetch the e-mail from a POP3 or IMAP account, and then convert it into a row of data in SQL Server.

SQL Server itself doesn't support polling an e-mail mailbox.

If you write this in a .NET language, you could potentially think about converting it into a SQL-CLR stored procedure, a chunk of .NET code that polls the mailbox, that resides in and is executed from SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. If I got this correctly, I need to setup a mail service in .NET that can receive emails and use that to extract the info from the email and store it in DB using SQL-CLR? I have used SMTP for sending/forwarding alerts using .NET applications but never have I used them for receiving emails from the client. Let me look into it and I will get back to you with the results.

Comment: @SorrelVesper; not **SMTP** - that's the protocol for **sending out** e-mails. What you need is a POP3 or IMAP account - either you have it hosted somewhere (on your company's mail server, or some external mail provider) and poll that mailbox on a regular basis, or you could write your own, in .NET (but that's a bigger undertaking) to handle incoming e-mails.